# Set-Clipboard only remembering the last value when called in rapid succession

Tags: powershell, clipboard

I am trying to create a powershell snippet that will copy the first column of a multi-line piped input to clipboard.

The intended usage is: `kubectl get pods | copyfirst`.
This should allow me to have all pod names in the clipboard, and use Win+V to select the individual pod name that I need.

What I have so far is:

```
function copyfirst {
    [CmdletBinding()]Param([Parameter(ValueFromPipeline)]$Param)
    process {
        $Param.Split(" ")[0] | Set-Clipboard
    }
}
```

The problem is - this only copies the last entry to clipboard, while all the others are ignored.

If I change `Set-Clipboard` to some other command - it works as intended. For example `echo` outputs all pod names, not just the last one.

Comment: Does `kubectl get pods ` output an array?

Comment: I believe so. `(kubectl get pods).GetType()` outputs
IsPublic = true, IsSerial = true, Name = Object[], BaseType = System.Array

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think [mklement0's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68421318/15339544) was the right one to begin with and I personally was not aware of this <kbd>Win + V</kbd> clipboard functionality. So, you were right, as it seems it can't capture the history when done in rapid succession.

By adding `Start-Sleep` it works fine:

```sh
function copyfirst {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline)]
        [object[]] $Param
    )

    process {
        $Param.Split(' ')[0] | Set-Clipboard
        Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 250
    }
}

@'
string1 string4
string2 string5
string3 string6
'@ -split '\r?\n' | copyfirst
```

It should capture `string1`, `string2` and `string3`.

Tweak the sleep timer until it's not too slow and it can capture everything.

---

After some testing, seems like `Start-Sleep` can be reduced to `-Milliseconds 250`, lower than that would produce inconsistent results.

Answer (score 4):

Note:

- This answer shows how to copy the first whitespace-separated field across *all* input lines *as a single clipboard entry*.
- As it turns out, the OP's intent was to copy each such field *separately* to the clipboard, to create a succession of entries that can be recalled via the Windows 10 clipboard-history function (<kbd>WinKey+V</kbd>), for which [Santiago Squarzon's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68421995/45375) provides a solution.

---

To copy data from *all* input objects, you must collect it in the `process` block and copy the collection to the clipboard in the `end` block, after all input objects have been processed:

```sh
function copyfirst {
    [CmdletBinding()]Param([Parameter(ValueFromPipeline)]$Param)
    begin {
        # Initialize the collection (list) that will collect data.
        $coll = [System.Collections.Generic.List[object]]::new()
    }
    process {
        # Add to the collection.
        $coll.Add($Param.Split(" ")[0])
    }
    end {
        # Copy the collection to the clipboard.
        # More efficient alternative:
        #    Set-Clipboard $coll
        $coll | Set-Clipboard
    }
}
```

The `process` block is called *for each input object*, and **`Set-Clipboard`** always replaces the previous content on the clipboard, which explains why only the *last* data item was placed there.

Note that stdout output from *external programs* is passed *line by line* through the pipeline.

---

Note that in your case there is a simpler alternative using a *simple* (non-[advanced](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Functions_Advanced)) function and the [automatic `$input` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#input):

```sh
function copyfirst {
  $input | ForEach-Object { $_.Split(' ')[0] } | Set-Clipboard
}
```

The potential downside of this approach is the loss of the *streaming* aspect of the pipeline (one-by-one processing), because a simple function's body is like an implicit `end` block, in which PowerShell provides the collected-up-front input objects via `$input`.

However, in this case, that doesn't matter, because you need to collect all data anyway.

You could speed up the operation a bit by using the [`.ForEach()` *array method*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Arrays#foreach) instead of the [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) *cmdlet*, though I doubt that it matters in this case.

Answer (score 3):

What I've found is that the clipboard would be overwritten when the `set-clipboard` is used in the same process. There is a `-append` but that appends to the last clipboard *value* rather than adding to the clipboard list.

What I ended up doing was building a command and executing it for each item in the array under a new process (which is slow!) as below:

```
function copyfirst {
    [CmdletBinding()]Param([Parameter(ValueFromPipeline)]$Param)
    
    foreach($line in $Param.split("`n")){
        $podName = $line.split(" ")[0]
        if ($podName -ne "NAME"){
            $scriptBlock = "Write-Output `"$podName`"  | Set-Clipboard; Start-sleep -milliseconds 1"
            Powershell $scriptBlock
        }
    }
}


"NAME READY STATUS RESTARTS AGE 
redis-fd794cd65-k9mhp 1/1 Running 0 3h15m
website-restrictor-c6f5bbd56-fxb59 1/1 Running 0 3h15" | copyfirst
```

This results in individual clipboard entries as seen when using `Windows Key + V`

Note the `Start-sleep -milliseconds 1` this is because of some weird behavior when executing the `set-clipboard` cmdlet very quickly, its noted here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-clipboard?view=powershell-7.1#notes

Comment: Thank you for your reply, unfortunately this does not seem to work.

My input is multi-line multi-column. I am attempting to copy first column of each line as a separate clipboard entry.

When I run your snippet as `kubectl get pods | copyfirst` it is asking me to provide parameters by hand.
`cmdlet Write-Output at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
InputObject[0]:`

Comment: Can you explain what the output looks like? eg. ```$output = kubectl get pods; $Output``` there was no mention of multi line multi column output

Comment: Sorry for the bad formating, can't figure out how to insert new lines in a comment.


`NAME                                 READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE` \newline
`redis-fd794cd65-k9mhp                1/1     Running   0          3h15m` \newline
`website-restrictor-c6f5bbd56-fxb59   1/1     Running   0          3h15m` \newline

Comment: My goal is to have `redis-fd794cd65-k9mhp` & `website-restrictor-c6f5bbd56-fxb59` copied to clipboard as a separate entries, so that I can paste them individually

Comment: No problem, I have edited my answer, try that

Comment: Your snippet works perfectly if the input is provided as a string (like in the second part of your answer).  It seems `kubectl get pods` returns the answer as array, so I had to tweak it a bit to work with it. The only chagne I made is replace `$Param.split("\`n")` with `$input` and it worked. Thank you for your help

Comment: No worries, please consider setting @Santiago Squarzon answer as the actual answer as he is correct about needing to wait longer than 1 millisecond for it to work, you don't need additional sessions as I stated